# Is the function that accepts the callback always clasificied as HGHER ORDER FUNCTION?

Tags: javascript

On google i found this definitions

- Function passed to another as an argument is known as a callback.
- `A function that accepts functions as parameters (callbacks)` or returns functions is known as a higher-order function.

all parts are clear to me except `A function that accepts functions as parameters (callbacks)`.

So when we have

```
function todo() {
  return function() { console.log('something') };
}
```

`todo` is HOC because it returns another function

but when we have

```
function todo(cb) {
    cb();
}

function addItem() {
    console.log('some item is added')
}

todo(addItem);
```

does this mean that `todo` is again HOC because it accepts function in its parameter, and the `addItem` is callback ?

I need to clarify this things and i don't know if i am right or not

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of your examples are HOC, so you are right.

Some more pratical examples of higher order functions:

```js
// Example 1: .reduce
const arrayToAddAllItems = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
const addAllItems = (a, b) => a + b

// Here .reduce is the HOC
const addedResult = arrayToAddAllItems.reduce(addAllItems)

console.log(addedResult)


// Example 2: .filter
const isTruthy = a => Boolean(a)

const arrayWithTruthyElements = [1, null, 0, false, 34, true]

// Here .filter is the HOC
const truthyElements = arrayWithTruthyElements.filter(isTruthy)
console.log(truthyElements)
```

In your particular example, HOC is useful because it can have internal variables that do not "leak" in the outer scope.

Observe:

```js
var todo = (function() {
  let todoCounter = 0
  return function (cb) {
    cb(todoCounter);
    todoCounter++
  }
})()

function addItem(counter) {
    console.log('some item is added', counter)
}

todo(addItem);
todo(addItem);
todo(addItem);
todo(addItem);
```

EDIT: here is a [good article](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/higher-order-functions-in-javascript-d9101f9cf528/) I found online showing more examples of modern JS higher order functions

Comment: i don't understad what you mean by `In your particular example, HOC is useful because it can have internal variables that do not "leak" in the outer scope.`

Comment: I just expanded on your example with `todo(addItem)` to show you a bit more advanced use-case for your HOC: Tracking how many todos you have put in without having a global `todoCounter` variable. Your example was already correct.